# Оптимизация запроса entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Имеется неприятная проблема с большим кол-вом .Include(), формируется запрос с большим кол-вом join-в откуда вытекает огромная нагрузка на БД. Как это можно оптимизировать?

```
ProgramSlots = context.ProgramSlots.Where(ps => ps.IsActive || loadAll)
                .Include(p => p.AllProgramSlotCandidates)
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.AllConditions")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.ProgramTerritories")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.Extentions")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.PriceFactors")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.Product")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.ProgramAllowances")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.ProgramPremiums")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.RiskConfigurations")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.RiskConfigurations.Risk")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.RiskConfigurations.Risk.Subrisks")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.InsuranceProvider")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.InsuranceProvider.FactorConfigurations")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.InsuranceProvider.InsuranceProviderRisks")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.InsuranceProvider.InsuranceProviderRisks.Risk")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.InsuranceProvider.PriceVariations")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.Product.Configuration")
                .Include("AllProgramSlotCandidates.Program.Product.FactorConfigurations")
                .ToList();
```

Comment: я боюсь представить в какой sql это транслировалось, а для чего Вам материализовать это, если есть возможность то стоит указать конкретные поля и запрос будет выполняться быстрее

Comment: Проблема в том что этот запрос создавал не я и по видимому все эти поля нужны.(MSSql)

Comment: Код хорошо покрыт тестами? Удаляйте строки `Include` (по одной) и проверяйте, правильно ли работает после этого код. / Как вариант, можно вместо энергичной загрузки использовать ленивую. Это приведёт к большему количеству запросов, т. е. нагрузка на БД даже увеличится, но она растянется по времени.

Comment: Довольно все данные нужны, нет какого-нибудь примера?

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть в какой запрос это транслируется, а затем посмотреть на план выполнения запроса. Пока же могу и так сказать, из опыта - при столь большом количестве таблиц `SQL Server` просто не успевает в отведённое время построить оптимальный план запроса, и только при большой удаче он (случайно) может его взять. В общем, предлагаю такой сценарий решения проблемы - получение текста и плана запроса, оптимизация запроса, фиксация плана выполнения (есть такая фича у `SQL Server`)

Comment: И да, попробуйте заифать код на две ветки - одна с `ps.IsActive`, другая для `loadAll`. Но не факт, что поможет

Comment: Я думал решить проблему с помощью хранимой процедуры. Как можно отловить запрос для создания запроса?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете EF Core 5 и выше, воспользуйтесь функционалом `Split Query`
Документацию можно найти [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries). Один из способов использования - применить `.AsSplitQuery()` к запросу.

Если версия EF Core ниже 5 - вам придется подгружать навигационные свойства другими способами, не через Include. Например, через  `entry.Collection(...).LoadAsync()`

Comment: Версия выше 5, но такого определения .AsSplitQuery() не содержит. А идея разделения запроса по частям мне очень нравится.

Comment: Странно, что нет, а какая у вас версия? Не путаете EF и EF Core?